# How to get Total of columns vertically in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

[image]

I have got the total horizontally, I want to achieve the last row which is in blue color, I have used this query

```
SELECT 
    DepartmentName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) High,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'Medium' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Medium,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Low,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        + SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'Medium' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        + SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total
FROM    
    TableName
GROUP BY 
    DepartmentName
```

How can I get the last row?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: sql server 2014

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [Grouping sets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
SELECT COALESCE(DepartmentName, 'Total'),
   SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) High,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'Medium' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Medium,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Low,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                        + SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'Medium' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                        + SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total
   FROM    TableName
   GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((DepartmentName), ())
```

Comment: @KalpeshKoli - Just to additionally note in case you visit that documentation link - empty parentheses () specify a single grand total group that sums all the groups specified in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Same that could be also achieve by using `ROLLUP`

```
SELECT 
      COALESCE(DepartmentName, 'Total') DepartmentName,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'High' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) High,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'Medium' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Medium,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Risk = 'Low' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Low,
      SUM(CASE WHEN Risk IN ('High', 'Medium', 'Low') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total   
FROM table
GROUP BY DepartmentName with ROLLUP
```